# infinite scroll with loading data through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a bug and I don't know how to fix that
I have an infinte scroll which is loading some pics and when I click on a pics it is show me the pics in popup but sometimes it does not and I don't know why

here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.masonry-brick').on('click', function(e){
    imgSrc = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    descTitle = $(this).find('.brick-desc-title span').html();
    shareLink = $(this).find('.fb-share').data('link');
    $('#popup-foodpics').find('img').attr('src', imgSrc);
    $('#popup-foodpics').find('.popup-desc-title span').html(descTitle);
    console.log(descTitle);
    displayPopupImg();

  });

  var load = false;
  $(window).scroll(function(){  
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ( $(document).height() - $(window).height() -10)  && load == false)  {
      if(load == false){
        var offset = $(".need_reload:last").data("offset");
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "load_pics.php",
          data: {offset : offset},
          cache: false,
          success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $('#masonry-container').append(data).masonry( 'reload' );

            $('.masonry-brick').on('click', function(e){
                imgSrc = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
                descTitle = $(this).find('.brick-desc-title span').html();
                shareLink = $(this).find('.fb-share').data('link');
                $('#popup-foodpics').find('img').attr('src', imgSrc);
                $('#popup-foodpics').find('.popup-desc-title span').html(descTitle);
                console.log('test >> '+descTitle);  // BUG HERE DISPLAY MANY TIMES INSTEAD OF ONE TIME
                displayPopupImg();
            });


            load = false;
          }
        });
      }
    }

  });
});

function displayPopupImg(){
    console.log($("#popup-foodpics").css('display'));
    if($("#popup-foodpics").css('display')=="none"){
         $(".blur img").addClass('blured');
    }
    else{
        $(".blur img").removeClass('blured');
    }
    $(".opacite-popup").toggle();
    $("#popup-foodpics").toggle();
}
```

I tried to debug with console.log and it is trigger many time the console.log instead of one time

Answer (score 0):

It is displaying multiple times because you are again registering on click event after ajax success request.

```
$.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "load_pics.php",
          data: {offset : offset},
          cache: false,
          success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $('#masonry-container').append(data).masonry( 'reload' );

            $('.masonry-brick').on('click', function(e){
                imgSrc = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
                descTitle = $(this).find('.brick-desc-title span').html();
                shareLink = $(this).find('.fb-share').data('link');
                $('#popup-foodpics').find('img').attr('src', imgSrc);
                $('#popup-foodpics').find('.popup-desc-title span').html(descTitle);
                console.log('test >> '+descTitle);  // BUG HERE DISPLAY MANY TIMES INSTEAD OF ONE TIME
                displayPopupImg();
            });


            load = false;
          }
        });
```

So, dont reregistering `$('.masonry-brick').on('click',function(){...}` on ajax success

Comment: if I remove in the success it will be never trigger

Comment: Okay, then remove event listener on masonry-brick before again assigning an event. $('.masonry-brick').off('click');

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem
I need to use delegate function

```
$(document).on("click", '.masonry-brick', function(event) {
```